# Cocoa webView DOMDocument manipulation issue using replaceSelectionWithMarkupString/Node

Tags: macos, cocoa, webkit, webview, domdocument

I am creating a document based application in Cocoa/Obj-C that will allow a user to select a word in a webView and hit a button that will wrap that selected text in random hash node.  For  example:

I have this document displayed in my webView:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>Hello to everybody</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Suppose the word **Hello** is selected by the user in the webView and they hit a button on the interface that calls this function:

```
NSString *randString = [myRandStringGenerator generateString];
NSString *selectedWords = [[webView getSelectedDOMRange] toString];
NSString *toWrite = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<%@>%@</%@>", randString, selectedWords, randString];
[webView replaceSelectionWithMarkupString:toWrite];
```

This function would result in an `DOMDocument` that is *identical* to the original.  **HOWEVER** if the selection **DOES NOT** contain the first character in a given node (in this case it is ), the function works perfectly!

So if the user selects **"ello to"** in the webView and the above function is called, the output is:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>H<kljsdhfla>ello to</kljsdhfla> everybody</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So my question is - why does this function fail when the selected `DOMRange` includes the first character inside of the #text of a `DOMNode` and succeed when it does not?

Also - I have tried this same function using the `[webView replaceSelectionWithNode:myNode]` function as well with the exact same effect.

Comment: Can I ask why you're generating random tags, rather than standard HTML ones?